# Different dash in GNOME 3.36.8

Tags: gnome

recently upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 (from 18.) and then Gnome 3.36.8; i got a dash different than other same set-up in my environment: File icon is a blue drawer, Ubuntu Help is a life buoy, that's no problem but what's bothering is Files duplicating its icon when mounting another partition (icon like a logo piece in a frame) even if the partition is in a Files tab in the main icon; Gnome 3.36.8 has different flavors ? Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are different flavors and there are a few things you can do. First, install `gnome-tweaks` so you can easily select different themes and icons:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Search for "tweaks" in your applications and the app is pretty self explanatory. You can change themes and icons from there.

It's also possible that you have regular gnome shell installed as well as the standard Ubuntu desktop.

If this is the case, you should be able to select one of the two from your login screen before you sign in (look for a gear icon or something to click on that will offer a selection of different desktop environments or flavors).

---

As for the extra icon for you mounted volumes, you can disable this feature by running the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

Supposedly, the feature is there to offer easy access to the mounted partition or device and to also provide an easy way to unmount the volume. Also, you can re-enable the feature at any time by running the following command instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true
```

[You can read more about the mounted drive issue here on OMG!ubuntu.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/hide-mounted-drives-ubuntu-dock)

Comment: Thanks,  
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false solved most of the problem.
Regarding gnome flavors : the options are Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Wayland and Unity, I keep Ubuntu.
Tweaks does not propose Yaru in Appearance, only Adwaita by default and some others; Yaru is the Appearance in other installation that sticks with more classical icons. Why Yaru did not get installed ? Depends on repository ?

Comment: @fb268 Not sure why it didn't install but you can search for relevant packages using: `apt-cache search yaru | grep -i yaru`